# CheckedChanged not firing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

I have done a lot of reading on this and every question I found involves ASP.NET. I'm using Winforms. I have a checkbox (Called **CheckboxPicture**) on my main form. I want to run a few commands when the state of this checkbox is changed by the user.

This should do it:

```
public void CheckboxPicture_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check State Changed");
}
```

However checking and unchecking the checkbox dont work. ASP.NET says you need

`Autopushback = true` but I'm not useing ASP.NET so im not sure where that would go.

Comment: In WinForms you use the WinForms designer. Select the CheckBox, show the Event properties and double click the CheckedChanged event. This will create the stub code for the event handler and opens it for you

Comment: Are you sure there is a `CheckboxPicture.CheckedChanged += CheckboxPicture_CheckedChanged` statement somewhere or at least something looking even remotely similar to this?

Comment: Are you actually subscribing to the event somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Hey Steve, Sorry, I'm new to C#.NET and didn't notice that events window. I was looking for it at the top of the code window like VB.NET and it was not there. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to add the handler with code as Mike Nakis suggests, although that is one possible way.  You can also just specify the handler you already created, in the checkbox's - properties - event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "winforms checkbox event" yields this as its first result:

[MSDN: CheckBox.CheckedChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

At some point, they mention:

> To run the example code, paste it into a project that contains an instance of type CheckBox named CheckBox1. **Then ensure that the event handler is associated with the CheckedChanged event.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Unfortunately, they don't show how to "ensure that the event handler is associated with the CheckedChanged event".

In short, somewhere within your code you have to have the following statement:

```
CheckboxPicture.CheckedChanged += CheckboxPicture_CheckedChanged
```

In other words, your `CheckboxPicture_CheckedChanged()` method will not be called by magic, you have to make sure it gets called when the corresponding event of the checkbox is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the form in your designer.  Click on the checkbox and look at the properties box.  Click on the event handlers and select your handler for the CheckedChanged handler property.

[image]