# Checkbox is not clickable | Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Basically, I have a checkbox in a content page, and I can't click it. It shows it correctly, but when I click on it, nothing happens. It doesn't even check the checkbox, nothing happens as if its an image.

I've tried:

```
IsEnabled="True"
IsChecked="True"
```

This is one of my 3 checkboxes:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbop"
          Grid.Row="1"
          CheckedChanged="Cbop_CheckedChanged"
          IsEnabled="True"
          Grid.Column="3" />
```

This is the cbop_CheckedChange:

```
        private void Cbop_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            cbhardcore.IsChecked = false;
            cbnormal.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

Full code of xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App3.Views.GameSettings">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="23*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbhardcore"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      CheckedChanged="Cbhardcore_CheckedChanged"
                      IsEnabled="True"
                      Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbnormal"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      CheckedChanged="Cbnormal_CheckedChanged"
                      IsEnabled="True"
                      Grid.Column="2" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbop"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      CheckedChanged="Cbop_CheckedChanged"
                      IsEnabled="True"
                      Grid.Column="3" />
            <Label x:Name="lblharcore"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Hardcore" />
            <Label x:Name="lblnormal"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="Normal" />
            <Label x:Name="lblop"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="3"
                   Text="Overpowered" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Full code of behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App3.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class GameSettings : ContentPage
    {
        public GameSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Cbop_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            cbhardcore.IsChecked = false;
            cbnormal.IsChecked = false;
        }

        private void Cbnormal_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            cbhardcore.IsChecked = false;
            cbop.IsChecked = false;
        }

        private void Cbhardcore_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            cbop.IsChecked = false;
            cbnormal.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens in your event method `Cbop_CheckedChanged`? Please add the code for this method to your post.

Comment: @RyanWilson it unchecks the other 2 checkboxes:
```
            cbhardcore.IsChecked = false;
            cbnormal.IsChecked = false;
```

Comment: Have you set a break point inside this method to see if clicking on the checkbox makes a call to this method?

Comment: @RyanWilson I have done that just now, and it doesn't reach the breakpoint.

Comment: Then that is an indication that something is wrong inside your project, your breakpoint should be getting hit inside of your event callback method if things are working correctly. Are you sure the event has been added to the checkbox, maybe check out this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891626/checkedchanged-not-firing)

Comment: But I've tried putting a button in the contentpage and that worked perfectly, so I don't get the problem

Comment: You should have a `MainWindow.xaml` item inside Soultion Explorer in Visual Studio, do you see that?

Comment: Do you mean MainPage? I see that one but no MainWindow

Comment: Yes, MainPage, if you expand it, you should find a file called: MainPage.xaml.cs, if you expand that, you should see a MainPage file, if you expand that, you should see a InitializeComponent() method, if you click that you will open a file called `MainPage.g.i.cs` inside of this, look for a method called `void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)`

Comment: It opens a file named: MainPage.xaml.g.cs
It only has a few lines which don't contain
`void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)`

Comment: Post your Cbop_CheckedChanged code, the signature might be incorrect and thus it's not called.

Comment: @NickKovalsky I've added it in the post

Comment: @WoJo What all do you have inside of the expansion of MainPage.xaml.cs? In my WCF project I see this inside of the method you say you can't find: `this.btnRun.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.btnRun_Click);` This is the callback method being added to the event .Click of a button on my Window. You should be able to find something like this but for your checkbox

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cbU61d6

Comment: When I double click `InitializeComponent() : void` inside of MainPage, this is all the code I get: https://hastebin.com/eqijucawol.cpp

Comment: Whats the version of xamarin forms you are using? Have you tried updating nuget packages?

Comment: I've updated to the latest version and nothing has changed..

Comment: Could the problem maybe be the way I'm calling the page?
`await Navigation.PushAsync(new GameSettings());`

Comment: post codes of `cbhardcore` `cbnormal` on the question. Issue with android or iOS?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Forms (So it's cross platform) and I debug on Android

Comment: Provide the full code of in xaml and code behind. I create a sample with 3 checkboxes and it works fine on my side.

Comment: I've done that just now @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: @WoJo Something tells me that the checkbox name isn't matching what you see in the xaml file where it is adding the method to the CheckChanged Event or else the method should be being hit in debug.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to simulate a set of RadioButtons. Have you considered trying that?

Comment: @WoJo (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127492/checkbox-checkchanged-property-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause:**  You put the `Label` and `CheckBox` in the same cell of grid(the same row and column). So the checkbox will be covered by the label .You can set the **BackgroundColor** of Label to check it .

```
<Label x:Name="lblharcore"
               BackgroundColor="red"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Hardcore" />
```

**Solution:**  Improve your layout.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="23*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">

            <Label x:Name="lblharcore"
                   BackgroundColor="red"                  
                   Text="Hardcore" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbhardcore"                     
                      CheckedChanged="Cbhardcore_CheckedChanged"
                      IsEnabled="True"
                       />
        </StackLayout>


        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label x:Name="lblnormal"                 
                   Text="Normal" />

            <CheckBox x:Name="cbnormal"                      
                      CheckedChanged="Cbnormal_CheckedChanged"
                      IsEnabled="True"
                       />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label x:Name="lblop"                 
                   Text="Overpowered" />

            <CheckBox x:Name="cbop"                    
                      CheckedChanged="Cbop_CheckedChanged"
                      IsEnabled="True"
                       />

        </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```